# Can Any one help me how to bind a code which pulls up a button automatically and a code which sends mass email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This is the code which pulls up a button:

```
Sub a()
    Dim btn As Button 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range


        For i = 1 To 3
        Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3))
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        With btn
         .OnAction = "btnS"
         .Caption = "Btn " & i
         .Name = "Btn" & i
   End With
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub btnS()
    MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

This is the code to send mass email:

```
Sub SendEmail(address_mail As String, subject_mail As String, mail_body As String)


Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = address_mail
    olMail.Subject = subject_mail
    olMail.Body = mail_body

   On Error GoTo Cancel

    olMail.Send

Cancel:

End Sub
Sub SendMassEmail()

Dim addressString As String
addressString = ""
row_number = 2



Do
DoEvents

    row_number = row_number + 1
    addressString = addressString & Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & row_number) & ";"


    Loop Until row_number = 999
Call SendEmail(addressString, Application.ActiveSheet.Range("F9"), Application.ActiveSheet.Range("F10"))

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you explain exactly what you're trying to do - what is the intended sequence of events here?  And what is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: Hello basically i dont understand the first code that well but it basically bulls up a button which when clicked sends out a mass email. So i want to collaborate my first code with the second which when run can pull up a button automatically

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see why you should bind both the codes in to one. It would be appreciate if you can clarify that a little bit.

Because as long as both the codes are in the same module, you can just create a new sub and run it when needed which will run both your codes one after the other:

```
Sub Bind()
Call a ' runs the first code
Call SendEmail ' runs the sendemail code
Call SendMassEmail ' runs the sendmassemail code
End Sub
```

The above will run all three codes one after the other. You can shuffle the order as you require.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so from what I understood from your comments you want one sub which will create **1 button** which when clicked will send out the emails.

Supposing that everything is alright with your second code, this is what you do:

```
Sub a()
    Dim btn As Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range

r = 1 ' select the row number where you want to create the button
c = 3 ' select the column number where you want to create the button

        Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c))
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        With btn
         .OnAction = ActiveSheet.Name & ".SendEmail" ' select the name of your second code here.
         .Caption = "Btn"
         .Name = "Btn"
   End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This way a button is created on the active sheet which when clicked will run your second code that should do the needful (provided your second code is also in the same sheet).

I trust that this is what you were looking for!'

**EDIT 2:**

From your comments it seems what you are after is a simple mail merge. If that's the case then please read more about "mail merge" as it is a lot easier will offer more functionality.

What you are asking can be done in excel, but it is a lot more complicated and this is how:

1. Create 2 sheets: (Sheet1) Names & Emails (Sheet2) Subject & Body
2. Add an ActiveX Button on sheet: Subject & Body
3. Make it look like the below:

[Sheet1 http://im63.gulfup.com/Bp8nJx.png](http://im63.gulfup.com/Bp8nJx.png)
[Sheet2 http://im63.gulfup.com/PtKK46.png](http://im63.gulfup.com/PtKK46.png)

Finally add the following code to your button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last filled row with emails

For Each Cell In Worksheets("Names & Emails").Range("B2:B" & LastRow) 'sets the range of cells with emails
    If Cell.Value = "" Then GoTo Line1 'loop until a blank cell is reached i.e. lastrow
    x = x & Cell.Value & "; " 'appends all the email in one line while adding "; " in between
Next

Emails = Left([x], Len([x]) - 2) 'removes the last 2 characters ("; ") from the appended string as the seperator is not needed after the last email

Line1:

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Emails 'inserts the appended line in the To field
        .Subject = Worksheets("Subject & Body").Range("B2").Value 'uses the value of B2 as the Subject of the Email
        .Body = Worksheets("Subject & Body").Range("B5").Value 'uses the value of B5 as the Body of the Email
        '.Display 'you can enable this line if you need to view the email before it's sent
        .Send 'sends the email
    End With

x = ""

End Sub
```

Now whenever you click the button, it will send an email all addresses in the list with the subject and body that you will select.

Comment: So the first code which calls the button needs a little bit of modification to fit the need of code's second part. So when i run the code it should bring up the button automatically in any sheet. if any one can try running the second part and see what it does and then kindoff of help me in fitting the first code in second

Comment: What does the button suppose to do when clicked? Because in your first code it looks like you are creating 3 new buttons.

Comment: Hey The first code isn't mine so i don't understand it that well. I just want to create one button which when clicked sends out mass email to people in a particular column which is specified in the second code

Comment: Thank you @CaptainABC for the help. I had a small question for you. so in the second code i am suppose to write a code where the body and subject for the email is supposed to be fetched from a another sheet which would be linked to the  sheet which has the emails in it.

Comment: @user2971393 Mmmm... you will have to be more specific. Is the Subject line & the Body same for all the people to whom the email is sent? If so, in which sheet and which cells are the Subject line & the body stored?

Comment: so I need to link and create a sheet with the main sheet which will only store subject and body for the emails automatically each when each time we run the code.

Comment: So imagine we have sheet with peoples names and their email id's and it has button on it when clicked the email will go to everyone in the sheet. So i want to link another sheet which would have subject and body for the emails in the main sheet. @CaptainABC

Comment: @user2971393 The answer was updated again. Hopefully this time it will work as you were requesting.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. Just wanted to ask where am i exactly suppose to put "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()" function. when i try running it puttting it under the sub a it said out of range error @CaptainABC

Comment: @user2971393 Just create an ActiveX Command Button: http://im62.gulfup.com/G5iL6F.png and then place it as per my second screenshot in my answer. Now open VisualBasic and paste the code in the answer under the sheet where you have placed the button.

Comment: For this code each time we copy the code to a different sheet we would have to create a button and put this function in it. Where as i wanted something to appear automatically @CaptainABC

Comment: @user2971393 Dear, I am not into spoon-feeding, the code is all there, if you would like to have a sub [Sub a() for example] to run on the active sheet that will automatically create a button, then use the `Sub a()` code that I have provided and then add the code of the command button on the same sheet and change `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` to `Sub SendEmail()`.